# How do I retrieve a specific strongly typed object from the AngularInMemoryWebApi's createDb result?

Tags: angular, api, web-services

I'm using the Angular-In-Memory-Web-Api to mock a backend while developing an application in Angular 7. My FakeBackendService appears as:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { InMemoryDbService, RequestInfo, ResponseOptions } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { Data } from './data';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FakeBackendService implements InMemoryDbService {

  dbData: Array<Data> = new Array(
    new Data(1, "Malcom", "09/11/1980", "Married"),
    new Data(2, "Reginald", "04/07/1992", "Single"),
  );
  constructor() { }

  createDb() {
    console.warn("createDb() CALLED");
    console.warn({ "tasks": this.dbData });
    return { "tasks": this.dbData }
  }
}
```

I then have a service that is calling this one with the intent to return a strongly typed observable, like so:

```
  base_url: string = "/api/";
  tasks_endpoint: string = "tasks";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getTasks() : Observable<Data[]> {
    return this.http.get<Data[]>(this.base_url + this.tasks_endpoint);
  }
```

This isn't working because the data being returned is really an object whose ['tasks'] value will actually contain the formatted data I'm seeking. I'm just not sure how to crack open the result of the get to return this particular data. The **Data** class itself is a basic poco as follows:

```
export class Data {
    public id: number;
    public name: string;
    public chosenDate: string;
    public optionSelected: string;

    public testme(): string {
        return "do i exist";
    }

    constructor(id: number, name: string, chosenDate: string, optionSelected: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.chosenDate = chosenDate;
        this.optionSelected = optionSelected;
    }

}
```

I've tried transforming the data in the component itself, but that doesn't seem to work. Furthermore, I feel like the service should return the correct data and the component shouldn't have to worry about it.

I'm new to Angular, but I've been doing a ton of research, video's, and tutorials. There are a myriad of things that I don't quite get right now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what is on your module as well. Also I would recommend using interfaces instead of classes for models (like yours one Data).

take a look at this sample, might help: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-angular-in-memory-web-api?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Hey, @domingo! Thanks for responding. I appreciate the link, but the scenario there is a little different than my own. Like many articles that demo the angular-in-memory-web-api, it assumes only 1 primary object for the mocked database. In my scenario, that won't be the case. This was the root cause of my confusion, or, at least, part of it. I now see that the collection stored in the RequestInfo is tied to the resourceUrl. Since my url was "/api/tasks", the "tasks" collection was saved to the RequestInfo.Collection property. Again, thanks for responding! I'm all ears if you have more thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Despite 2 days of purposed researched and even more hours of general research, it would be that less than 20 minutes after I breakdown to post this question I arrive at a solution. I'm not sure if it's a good one, mind you, but it works.

I had already previously discovered the responseInterceptor method. The issue I had then was that it presumed there was only 1 set collection of data. This is what it was:

```
  protected responseInterceptor(res: ResponseOptions, ri: RequestInfo): ResponseOptions {
    res.body = this.dbData;
    return res;
  }
```

This works and returns data that is strongly typed, but what if my createDb() method returned other data such as :

```
  createDb() {
    return { "tasks": this.dbTasks, "schedules":this.dbSchedules }
  }
```

This means that only 1 of my data sets could ever be returned and it'd have to be set in stone. That's what I thought, at least. Then I actually logged the RequestInfo object to the console and saw it had a collection property whose data was strongly typed. My solution at the moment is this:

```
  protected responseInterceptor(res: ResponseOptions, ri: RequestInfo): ResponseOptions {
    if (ri.resourceUrl.indexOf('tasks') > -1) {
      res.body = ri.collection;
    }
    return res;
  }
```